# Find String between two Strings and replace a part of it

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode9

I have some problems and need some help with Objective-C.
I'm trying to find a String, let's say it is called `<font>` in a XML File and within the  Tag I want to replace a word in a sentence.

Something like this

```
<body>
...
<font>Let's do a quick test</font>
...
</body>
```

For example:
Between `<font>` and `</font>` I want to replace the word `quick` to `good`.
And those changes has to overwrite the XML-File.

If someone can help me please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: You can use a `NSRegularExpression` for that, with a pattern maybe like this one: `<font>([.\s\S]*?)<\/font>`?

Comment: That can do the trick: `NSError *errorRegex = nil; NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(<font>([.\\s\\S]*?))(quick)(([.\\s\\S]*?)<\\/font>)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&errorRegex]; [regex replaceMatchesInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length]) withTemplate:@"$1good$4"];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Firstly get the string between two string using this method

  ```
  NSString *str1 = [self getSubString:fullString fromRangeOfString:@"<font>" endWith:@"</font>"];
  ```

-

```
-(NSString *)getSubString:(NSString *)string fromRangeOfString:(NSString *)rangeStr endWith:(NSString *)endStr{
    NSString *param = @"";
    NSRange start = [string rangeOfString:rangeStr];
    if (start.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        param = [string substringFromIndex:start.location + start.length];
        NSRange end = [param rangeOfString:endStr];
        if (end.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            param = [param substringToIndex:end.location];
        }
    }
    return param;
}
```

- Now str1 contains @"Let's do a quick test" then replace the word quick to good

  ```
  NSString *str2 = [str1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"quick" withString:@"good"];
  ```
- There are some more methods provided by Apple which help you to replace with more options

/* Replace all occurrences of the target string in the specified range with replacement. Specified compare options are used for matching target. If NSRegularExpressionSearch is specified, the replacement is treated as a template, as in the corresponding NSRegularExpression methods, and no other options can apply except NSCaseInsensitiveSearch and NSAnchoredSearch.
*/

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement options:(NSStringCompareOptions)options range:(NSRange)searchRange NS_AVAILABLE(10_5, 2_0);
```

/* Replace all occurrences of the target string with replacement. Invokes the above method with 0 options and range of the whole string.
*/

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement NS_AVAILABLE(10_5, 2_0);
```

/* Replace characters in range with the specified string, returning new string.
*/

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range withString:(NSString *)replacement NS_AVAILABLE(10_5, 2_0);
```

- Write resulting str2 to XML

................................<><><><><><><>...........................

```
XMLWriter *xmlWriter = [[XMLWriter alloc] init];
// start writing XML elements
[xmlWriter writeStartElement:@"font"];
[xmlWriter writeCharacters:str2];
[xmlWriter writeEndElement];
```

Thanks,
Hope this helps you.